# What does Integer mean in java

Tags: java

I  am looking to find out what Integer not int but Integer means here is the code in question

```
public class BasicSearch {
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public static int binarySearch(Integer[] a, int x)
    {
        int low=0;
        int high = a.length - 1;
        int mid;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (a[mid].compareTo(x)<0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0)
            high = mid -1;
            else
                return mid;
        }
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int SIZE = 8;
        Integer[] a = new Integer[SIZE];
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
            a[i] = new Integer(i * 2);
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE*2; i++)
            System.out.println("Found " + i + " at " + binarySearch(a, new Integer(i)));
    }


    }
```

I dont know if Integer is a keyword or what Could I get any help?

Comment: It is terrible that people unable to simply google 'java integer'. How will they reuse the SO answers?

Comment: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) should answer all of your questions.

Comment: I googled java integer it shows int not The Integer as I stated

Comment: it wasn't a clear enough query and did not answer my question so I asked on here so that I may understand it and i do know

Comment: From the trails: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html

Comment: Cool I already have the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, we have a concept called [Wrapper Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class). Wrapper classes are objects that wrap primitive types. For example, `char` has a `Character` wrapper class. These classes are designed to give object methods to what function like primitive types.

All Primitive wrapper classes are also immutable, which means that while you can access the data, you can not manipulate it once it has been created.

[This Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) lists all of the wrapper classes in Java.

As PetarMinchev stated, there is no need to use them in this code.

Answer (score 4):

`Integer` is a class which wraps an `int`, which is a primitive type.

No need to use `Integer` here, it just wastes resources. You can make the comparison without `compareTo`, but with simple `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a class which wraps the ordinary primitive int.
It can use in some situations when you need a class to represent integer instead of primitive type.

one common example is when you need to make a generic collection:

```
List<Integer> list;
```

also, The Integer class have [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), so it sometimes can be more convenient to use it

Answer (score 0):

Integers are the wrapper class for int(which is primitive data type).

So in reality Integer is nothing but just a Class created by Java in which they have implemented some utility method.

No need to see it as any magic thing, its just the objects that you are dealing there. with some functions.

You can very well use int in this code where you want.

the best utility of using Integer class will be places you want to pass parameter by refernce or use lot of utility functions given by them.

For your simple compare operations like these its better to use int.